# Using subtotals to create another weighted column

Tags: excel, weighted, subtotal

I have an Excel worksheet with categories for which I use the subtotal function to obtain the totals.

I would like to create another column that offers a weighted value corresponding to the row and its equivalent ratio to the categories subtotal eg percentage.

*without PivotTables is it possible?

```
╔══════════════════════╦════════════╦════════════════════╦═════════════════╗
║      Exam Paper      ║ Out of 100 ║ Weighted per paper ║     Subject     ║
╠══════════════════════╬════════════╬════════════════════╬═════════════════╣
║ Maths I              ║         65 ║ =C2/$C$4*100       ║ Maths           ║
║ Maths II             ║         45 ║ =C3/$C$4*100       ║ Maths           ║
║                      ║        110 ║ =C4/$C$4*100       ║ Maths Total     ║
║ Physics I            ║         53 ║ 44.17              ║ Physics         ║
║ Physics Practicals   ║         67 ║ 55.83              ║ Physics         ║
║                      ║        120 ║ 100.00             ║ Physics Total   ║  
║ Chemistry I          ║         70 ║ 63.64              ║ Chemistry       ║   
║ Chemistry Practicals ║         40 ║ 36.36              ║ Chemistry       ║
║                      ║        110 ║ 100.00             ║ Chemistry Total ║
║                      ║        340 ║                    ║ Grand Total     ║
╚══════════════════════╩════════════╩════════════════════╩═════════════════╝
```

Comment: Provide some sample data.

Comment: Sure - create another column that offers weighted value and equivalent ratio to the category's subtotal - format as a percent.

Comment: If you upload more information, it would be easy help

Comment: I have added an example, of course the list is much much larger.

Comment: Solved it  Replace 
=C2/$C$4*100  with  =C2/INDEX($C$2:$E$11,MATCH(CONCATENATE(E2," Total"),$E$2:$E$11,0),1)*100   The match using the concat finds the total row then the index returns the subtotal figure.